# Access Points Properties in Android

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, access-point

I am developing an app that need to connect to several Wi-Fi access points based on their properties. An [example](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.usenix.org/events/mobisys06/full_papers/p233-nicholson.pdf) is to select better access point for improved connectivity. The details of the access points may not be known ahead in a new environment. How do I programmatically find the properties (specifically, name and make/manufacture, signal strength) of the access points using Android phones? Can I know the manufacturer/make of the access point (so that it can be used to infer associated stored features in the app) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find whole details of wifi using the library 'wifiManager'

```
WifiManager wManager;
List<ScanResult> wifiList; 

wManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
// Inside BroadcastReceiver()
wifiList = wManager.getScanResults();
for (int i=0; i<wifiList.size(); i++){
     ScanResult scanresult = wManager.getScanResults().get(i);                        
     System.out.println("SSID: "+ssid);
     System.out.println("RSSI: "+scanresult.level);
     System.out.println("Frequency: "+scanresult.frequency);
     System.out.println("BSSID: "+scanresult.BSSID);
     System.out.println("Capability: "+scanresult.capabilities);
}
```

Here the RSSI gives the signal strength in db, normally it varies from 0 to -100.
Also checkout the BroadcastReceiver().